# Fetch all record including particular fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I am working with Elasticcsearch 7.3. I want to fetch only two records of all the documents using JAVA Api from my index. I am using the following code but it returning the null object.

```
        RestHighLevelClient client;

        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        sourceBuilder.fetchSource("recipe_ID,recipe_url", null);
        sourceBuilder.from(0);
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("recipes");
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        SearchHit searchHit = searchResponse.getHits().getAt(0);

        String resultString = searchHit.getSourceAsString();

        return resultString;
```

I need to include only two fields **recipe_ID** and **recipe_url** in my result.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path, although [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html#_source_filtering) requires you to specify your fields in an array like this:

```
    String[] includeFields = new String[] {"recipe_ID", "recipe_url"};
    sourceBuilder.fetchSource(includeFields, null);
```

Comment: I want it to return the values of just these fields from all of the documents. How could I do so ?

Comment: That's what the above code does. Have you tried it?

Comment: It returns me 0 hits.

Comment: Are you sure you actually have something in your index?